# Use gparted to copy CentOS boot volume

Tags: centos, partition, clone, gparted

I can't seem to copy all partitions from my boot device (SDA) to my new ssd (SDB). For some reason the copy function is greyed out for the SDA2 partition. I can only copy the SDA1 partition.

I'm booting form a live gparted image.

Can anyone advice. It's a normal CentOS installation as far as I know. I attached some screenshots with more info.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not a regular partition, it's an LVM.

Comment: Any alternatives on how to duplicate this entire volume? I also tried DD but didn't work either, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, this looks largely as normal CentOS system. But, the work you're doing could easily be done even online, from within the running system, even without service interruption. What you need to do is basically to create partitions on the new disk, copy boot files to first partition, add second one as LVM PV to the existing volume group, migrate volumes and reinstall boot loader to second disk. Then you may remove the former PV from the group and remove old disk completely. There are many how-tos on the internet how to do this, I bet some of them even exist on ServerFault.

Comment: Just to check, DD won't work on this? Because it seems a lot more straightforward to me. THX!

Answer (score 0):

I just took out the drive and mounted it on my mac with a USB caddy and did a full DD copy to another SSD. Was the simplest option for my case. I don't understand why DD didn't work on the server itself, even when booting from a live CD. It did take 2 days for 1TB...